# Python IDLE 3.9.1 file not opening in windows

Tags: python, windows, crash

I had saved a python file after working on it for sometime, but now when I open it, Python 3.9.1 opens a window then immediately closes. I had done lots of work on this and don't want it to go to waste. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Perhaps you need to start `IDLE` first and open the file from inside that?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using the **Open** option when you right-click or you are simply double-clicking the script, the program will run and close so fast you won’t even see it.

Here are two options I use:

1. Open up the Command Prompt. You can easily do this by going to the address bar of your File Explorer and enter ‘cmd’. If you’re in the directory where your script is, the current working directory of the Command Prompt will be set to that. From there, run `python my_script.py`.
2. Edit your script with IDLE. If you’re using an IDE, it should be nearly the same process, but I don’t use one so I wouldn’t know. From the editor, there should be a method for running the program. In IDLE, you can just using *Ctrl + F5*.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on it and clicken "open with". Then choose Python IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the file instead of editing it.

You have to right-click the file and you should the "edit with idle" option.
[image]